# How to check if image exists before setting it?

Tags: gtk

I am trying to update a GtkImage with gtk_image_set_from_file(), but how can I check if this image exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_file_test` beforehand or use `gdk_pixbuf_load_from_file` + `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf`